# Securing AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have have an existing application and we are developing the new APIs required for our application in AWS.

We want to enable role based access control to our AWS API without migrating our users to AWS Cognito. We think we might need to use Developer Identity Provider and IAM Roles, but not sure how the users from our application will be attached to IAM Roles. Any help in this direction will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am new to AWS.

Comment: So you already have an application which has a API implemented with role based access control, which needs to be served thorough API Gateway?

Comment: We are planning to develop all the new APIs needed for our existing legacy application in AWS infrastructure / service(s). The exisiting application has user roles / permissions defined. We want to use same roles / permissions for the new APIs exposed via AWS API Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at [API Gateway Custom Authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html).

This way you can plug your already existing authorization system into the API gateway. I wouldn't use IAM roles as long as you are not sharing AWS resources directly with your users.

If you are only using role based access controls for your application, using existing application roles is absolutely fine. You just need to make them accessible, so the custom authorizer lambda can validate the authorization against it.

Comment: Thanks Jens Walter. Does this mean that the API Gateway Custom Authorizers should somehow get the Permission associated with the given token from the existing application and convert that into IAM Policy?

Comment: For API access you won't need IAM policies since the gateway has its own policy framework. IAM policies are only necessary if you want to access AWS resources like S3, DynamoDB or RDS directly. In your case, I assumed that the application controls the access to the backend and the gateway should only allow/deny access to API resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to use the existing roles and permissions of your application for the API, there are several options available.

- Using IAM authorizer with Cognito [User Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html) feature recently introduced and map your existing roles, to attributes from Developer Identity provider and map them to Groups. Using this, you can define, different API Gateway resources to be accessed by different user groups by defining them in IAM policies.
- Using Custom Authorizer you will need to write your custom authorizer code to do the authentication as well as authorization.